# How to separate strings to have required part in R?

Tags: r, string

I have created a `list.files` using the following code

```
#Make a list of the files
files <- list.files(path="E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB", 
                    pattern=glob2rx("*.tif$*"), full.names=TRUE)

files

 [1] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET.tif"
 [2] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_03.MAR.2022_ET.tif"
 [3] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_04.DEC.2021_ET.tif"
 [4] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_06.FEB.2022_ET.tif"
 [5] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_10.MAR.2022_ET.tif"
 [6] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_11.APR.2022_ET.tif"
 [7] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_13.DEC.2021_ET.tif"
 [8] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_15.FEB.2022_ET.tif"
 [9] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_18.NOV.2021_ET.tif"
[10] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_19.MAR.2022_ET.tif"
[11] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_20.DEC.2021_ET.tif"
[12] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_22.FEB.2022_ET.tif"
[13] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_26.MAR.2022_ET.tif"
[14] "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_30.JAN.2022_ET.tif"
```

Now I want to extract only `TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET` part (part 7) for all the 14 lines and make like the following

```
c("TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET", "TSEB_03.MAR.2022_ET", "TSEB_04.DEC.2021_ET", 
  "TSEB_06.FEB.2022_ET", "TSEB_10.MAR.2022_ET", "TSEB_11.APR.2022_ET", 
  "TSEB_13.DEC.2021_ET", "TSEB_15.FEB.2022_ET", "TSEB_18.NOV.2021_ET", 
  "TSEB_19.MAR.2022_ET", "TSEB_20.DEC.2021_ET", "TSEB_22.FEB.2022_ET", 
  "TSEB_26.MAR.2022_ET", "TSEB_30.JAN.2022_ET")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe drop the path? `list.files(path="E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB", pattern=glob2rx("*.tif$*"))`

Comment: @zx8754 If I do what you have suggested, the rasters are not getting loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `basename` + `gsub`:

```r
x <- c("E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET.tif",
  "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_03.MAR.2022_ET.tif")

gsub("\\.tif$", "", basename(x))
#[1] "TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET" "TSEB_03.MAR.2022_ET"
```

Comment: `.` should be `\\.`, and to be maximally defensive I would use the expression `\\.tif$`. Or `tools::file_path_sans_ext`, but that function is actually *not recommended* since it’s buggy.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good points, I edited

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET.tif",
   "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/TSEB_03.MAR.2022_ET.tif")

str_extract(x, "(?<=\\/)(.*)(?=.tif)")
```

**Regex explanation:**

We need to stract whatever, capturing group (`.*`), with two condition. *First condition* is look behind of capturing group (`?<=`) for `/`, I use `\\` to escape character. *Second condition*, look ahead of capturing group (`?=`) for extension `.tif`.

Output:

```
[1] "TSEB_03.APR.2022_ET" "TSEB_03.MAR.2022_ET"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate `"(?<=\\/)(.*)(?=.tif)"` part? Which symbol is used for what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

To expand my comment to avoid *regex*, we already know the folder where files live and they all are under the same folder, so get the filenames without folder:

```
myFolder = "E:\\ICAR PDF\\Data\\Tridip\\Desktop\\TSEB/"
files <- list.files(path = myFolder, pattern=glob2rx("*.tif$*")) # default full.names = FALSE
```

Then read your files, something like:

```
dataList <- lapply(paste0(myFolder, files), myLoadRasterFunction)
```

And if we need the filenames they are readily available without *regex* in *files* object.